# How can I print my outcome as a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-3.4

I've created a program where the output prints as, for example, `36, 6, 2, 1`.

I want it to print `[36, 6, 2, 1]`.

This is my current code:

```
def collatz(n):

    print(n, end = ', ')

    while (n > 1):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n=int(n**0.5)
        else:
            n=int(n**1.5)
        if n == 1:
            print(1)
        else:
            print(n, end = ', ')
```

I am not sure what to edit at this point as I've tried a lot messing with the print statements and I have seen in other posts where `print(*n, ...)` was used but I get the error:

```
TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not int.
```

Which I get why it wouldn't work so I'm lost at this point.

Comment: Why not append to a list wherever you are printing and then print your list?

Comment: You can also print `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end, but constructing a list is the better method.

Comment: The error message does not match the code.

Comment: @DonkeyKong I knew I needed to append to a list, I just was not sure where to implement it exactly. 2 of the replies below did answer it though.

Comment: @Selcuk That, I was not aware could be done or how it could be done. One of the replies on the bottom did show how that would be done and I will use it for future reference! Still new to python so trying to learn the ins and outs.

Comment: You can clean the code by putting `if n == 1: print(1)` outside the loop, and leaving only `print(n, end=',')` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to create a list and append the values of `n` to the list. In this way you can take the advantage of the builtin functionality of `str(list)` which automatically adds `[` and `]` to the end while printing.

A sample code can be

```
def collatz(n):

    templist = [n]    
    while (n > 1):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n=int(n**0.5)
        else:
            n=int(n**1.5)
        if n == 1:
            templist.append(1)
        else:
            templist.append(n)
    print(templist)
```

Now when you run `collatz(36)` you get `[36, 6, 2, 1]`

Comment: I think I can work with this one though. It is a lot cleaner and simpler and the simpler the better. I am still new to Python so anything helps and this was a significant help! Thank you very much! I knew it was something so tiny.

Answer (score 2):

To control how its printed, simply print the `[` and `]` separately. Don't confuse how its *printed* with how its *stored* or what data type it has.

```
def collatz(n):

    print('[{}'.format(n), end=', ')

    while (n > 1):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n=int(n**0.5)
        else:
            n=int(n**1.5)
        if n == 1:
            print(1, end=', ')
        else:
            print(n, end = ', ')
    print(']', end='')
```

Comment: This worked but the only downside is that there is an extra space after the 1. 

So it looks like this: `[...8, 2, 1, ]`.

Update: I saw the extra space after looking at the code a 5th time and fixed it. This is perfect!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your function considerably by getting rid of the `if` condition since

```
if n % 2 == 0:
  n=int(n**0.5)
else:
  n=int(n**1.5)
```

Is the same as: `n % 2 + 0.5`

And also using recursion rather than iteration. So your `collatz` function can simply implemented as this:

```
def collatz(n):
  if n <= 1:
    return [1]
  return [n] + collatz(int(n ** (n % 2 + 0.5)))
```

`collatz(n)` will now return an array which is fine, its better if functions have a single responsibility. Now you can wrap it in a function which prints the array in a Python-like format:

```
def print_collatz(n):
  return str(collatz(n))
```

So you can simply call:

```
print_collatz(36)
# [36, 6, 2, 1]
```

To return an array-formatted string:

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list and print its string representation:

```
def collatz(n):

    my_list = []

    my_list.append(n)

    while (n > 1):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n=int(n**0.5)
        else:
            n=int(n**1.5)
        if n == 1:
            my_list.append(1)
        else:
            my_list.append(n)

    print(str(my_list))
```

Comment: What list? There is no list in the question.

Comment: The question is "How can I print my outcome as a list?" and there's no list in the question?

Comment: @Bonifacio2 There is no list in the question, no. You added a list. Looks like the OP was confused by the notion that to print a list, you need a list. so answering with just `print(str(list(...)))` was hardly helpful.